# View factor model for bifacial pv system

Tags: python-3.x, pvlib

how can I model bifacial pv system with view factor model , calculate total ground irradiance and irradiance for rear side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pvlib's infinite sheds model: https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/bifacial.html